# "Failed to start 'npm'" error message when accessing page remotely

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application running in docker on a Raspberry Pi that when I try to access via the Pi, it shows up just fine. When I try to access it on the local network, I get the following exception page: [image: Error Page]

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS builder
WORKDIR /source

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm --version

COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./ ./

RUN dotnet publish "./AspNetCoreApp.csproj" --output "./dist" --configuration Debug --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /source/dist .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspNetCoreApp.dll"]
```

Any ideas why it fails when I connect on a different computer?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your dockerfile and asp.net core project template? Do you develop with spa in docker container?

Comment: @TaoZhou - I just updated my post with the dockerfile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this error, it indicates that you did not install node in your image.

For built-in ms docker image, it did not install node by default, you could try command like below to install node.

```
ROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
# BEGIN MODIFICATION - Node is needed for development (but not production)
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes nodejs
# END MODIFICATION

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

**Update**

It seems you are in production environment. For the reason why it works when removing `environment: - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`, it is caused by

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

For development environment, it will use `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");`.

Comment: I don't get the npm error when I access the site locally, only when remoting in.

Comment: @CodeSlinger512 What do you mean by access locally?

Comment: I meant accessing the page on the computer that is hosting it. I found out what the problem was... It was an auto generated line produced by dotnet in the docker-compose.override.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

removing

```
environment: - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

from the compose.override file fixed all this. I'm not sure why it's the problem.